# Centering Arrows in PGF Plots Quiver

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, arrows, tikz-3dplot

I'm trying to get quiver plot to play nicely with a grid. I'd either like the arrows to be centered (so half way point of the arrow is in the center of each cel, or the start of the arrow is in the center of the cell.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots,}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\def\length{sqrt((2.*x^2-2.2-2.*y^2)^2  + (4.*x^2*y)^2 )}

\begin{tikzpicture}[enter image description here][1]
    \begin{axis}[   enlargelimits = false ,
            view={0}{90},
            domain=-2:2,
            axis equal image
        ]
        \addplot3 [gray,quiver={u={(2.*x^2-2.2-2.*y^2)/\length}, v={4.*x^2*y/\length}, scale arrows=0.2}, -stealth,samples=12] {0};
    \end{axis}

    \begin{scope}%[xshift=4pt,yshift=4pt]
        \draw[step=3.99mm, blue] (0,0) grid (5.5,5.5);
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I'm not sure if this is possible with the "every arrow" option. 
Here's what I have so far

[image]

Comment: The grid seems not to be "consistent" with the axes because you're not using `axis cs:`. As a consequence, you have 13 boxes (if I count correctly) between `-2` and `2` but 12 arrows (because you set `samples=12`). I don't know how to answer the underlying question, though, but I'd like to kindly ask you to fix this issue in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\def\length{sqrt((2.*x^2-2.2-2.*y^2)^2  + (4.*x^2*y)^2 )}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[   enlargelimits = false ,
            view={0}{90},
            domain=-2:2,
            minor x tick num=2, 
            minor y tick num=2,
            axis equal image, grid=both,
            minor grid style={blue,very thin},
            axis equal image
        ]
        \addplot3[white,quiver={u={(2.*x^2-2.2-2.*y^2)/\length}, v={4.*x^2*y/\length}, scale arrows=0.2}, -stealth,samples=12] {0};
        \addplot3[domain=-11/6:11/6,gray,quiver={u={(2.*x^2-2.2-2.*y^2)/\length}, v={4.*x^2*y/\length}, scale arrows=0.2}, -stealth,samples=12] {0};
    \end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Explanation: apart from the fact that there were 13 boxes for 12 arrows per row, `pgfplots` really seems to move the arrows to the boundaries. In this proposal, I shrink the domain for the arrows by 1/12.